Accessing local python module from two separate services with additional contexts in Docker
I've got a docker project where I have a local python module that is used by two services in the docker container. I'm trying to use the additional-contexts field in the compose file to allow both services to copy this module in to their image.
The docker project structure looks like this
├── docker-compose-aws.yml
├── docker-compose.override.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── ecs-params.yml
├── model_server
│   └── app
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── app
│       │   └── run_model_server.py
│       └── requirements.txt
├── shared
│   └── models.py
└── web_server
    └── app
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── app
        │   └── main.py
        └── requirements.txt

The compose file looks like this:
name: my_docker
services:
  model-server:
    build:
      context: ./model_server/app
      additional_contexts:
          assets: ./shared
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: "true"
    command:
      - python
      - run_model_server.py
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    image: template-model-server:latest
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./model_server/app
        target: /app
        bind:
          create_host_path: true
    working_dir: /app/app
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 6379
        published: "6379"
        protocol: tcp
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web_server/app
      additional_contexts:
          assets: ./shared
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: "true"
    command:
      - python
      - main.py
      - serve
    depends_on:
      model-server:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      RELOAD: "True"
    image: template-web-server:latest
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 5042
        published: "5042"
        protocol: tcp
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./web_server/app
        target: /app
        bind:
          create_host_path: true
    working_dir: /app/app
networks:
  default:
    name: my_docker_default

The docker file looks like
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc build-essential cmake \
    git python3-dev gcc && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt dev-requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

ARG INSTALL_DEV=false
RUN bash -c "if [ $INSTALL_DEV == 'true' ] ; then pip install --no-cache-dir -r dev-requirements.txt && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt ; else pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --upgrade ; fi"

COPY app app/
COPY --from=assets ./shared app/shared
COPY scripts scripts/

When I try to import the shared python module with import shared.models I get a ModuleNotFoundError.
Using docker compose build I get a bit more information on the error:
failed to solve: shared: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/shared:latest: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed


Can you use the traditional Docker method of setting the build context directory to the parent directory of all of the directories you need?  I'd also consider using a multi-stage build to package your shared library into a Python wheel file that you can pip install.

(Since you're doing some complicated assembly of the application directory in the Dockerfile, the volumes: that bind-mount host content over /app will hide all of this work, and you'll get inconsistent results, maybe even the import error you're getting at the end; consider removing that volumes: block.  You also don't normally need command: or working_dir: overrides, custom networks:, or to name the built image:.)

ok thanks for this. I've tried to do it by setting context to parent directory but it becomes really confusing. I might try via multi-stage build as you suggest

The traditional Docker approach to this (see How to include files outside of Docker's build context?) is to set the build: { context: } directory to the parent directory of all of the content you need to include, and then use relative paths to that top-level directory on the left-hand side of Dockerfile COPY instructions.
# model_server/app/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc build-essential cmake \
    git python3-dev gcc && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY model_server/app/requirements.txt model_server/app/dev-requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

ARG INSTALL_DEV=
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt ${INSTALL_DEV+-r dev-requirements.txt}

# NOTE: left-hand side of these COPYs is relative to project root
COPY model_server/app/app app/
COPY shared app/shared
COPY model_server/scripts scripts/

WORKDIR /app/app
CMD ["./run_model_server.py"]

In the Compose file, you're assembling the contents of the app subdirectory from several places.  It's important that you not bind-mount another directory over this, since this will hide everything that's in the Dockerfile.  In the Dockerfile above I've included a couple of important directives (a default CMD for the image, correctly setting the WORKDIR) and you should be able to reduce the Compose file fragment to just
services:
  model-server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: "true"
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
      REDIS_HOST: redis

where a number of options I've stripped out you're either providing the default values already (dockerfile:, networks:), correct settings are in the Dockerfile (command:, working_dir:), or Compose can provide a reasonable default on its own (image: when used with build:).

I would generally recommend making the shared directory a standalone Python library; for example, give it its own pyproject.toml and pip install ../../shared in your non-Docker development virtual environment.  The setup you show has an app directory with files manually copied around, and this will be hard to work with in any environment other than the isolated immutable Docker image.
This setup also includes some expensive build tools.  One approach you can use here is to build a Python virtual environment in a multi-stage build.  The first stage builds a virtual environment, and the second COPYs it into the main image.  The two images must use the exact same Python base image and the virtual environment must be in the exact same path.
ARG python=python:3.10-slim-bullseye

# First stage: build the virtual environment
FROM ${python} AS build
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      cmake \
      git
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Install application dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY model_server/app/requirements.txt model_server/dev-requirements.txt ./
ARG INSTALL_DEV=
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt ${INSTALL_DEV+-r dev-requirements.txt}

# Install the shared library
WORKDIR /shared
COPY shared/ ./
RUN pip install .

# Main image
FROM ${python}

# Copy the entire virtual environment from the build stage,
# including the preinstalled shared library
COPY --from=build /venv/ /venv/
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application in
WORKDIR /app
COPY model_server/app/app app/
COPY model_server/scripts scripts/

WORKDIR /app/app
CMD ["./run_model_server.py"]

This will work with the same Compose file as above, but the final image will be smaller.  If you really do want to bind-mount local source code over /app/app it will work, but be aware that you haven't run the code actually built into the image if you go to deploy this setup.

thanks for your detailed answer. Could you explain why the additional contexts approach fails to work though? it seems like it would be the easiest way to achieve this if it did work.
